# How to change "Block third-party cookies" in Chromium through ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am using **ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106** with **Chromium 80.0.3987.122** and I am running some Javascript tests inside Chromium and fetch results using the driver.

I get this error after I updated both Chromium and the driver (from version 67):

> Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

After some googling around, I found the issue reported [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-localstorage-property-from-window-access-is-denied-for-this-document). Basically, the problem is this setting:

[image]

However I am not finding a way to change its value to `false` using the driver's API.

---

#### Attempts

I checked:

- [Chromium flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
- [Chromium switches](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)
- [Chromium prefs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc)

But that option does not seem to be there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem.
You can use custom chrome profile setting. I used my own chrome profile setting and succeeded to use selenium with setting the option false.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities#TOC-Use-custom-profile-also-called-user-data-directory-

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It could be improved by including the relevant information from the linked site in the answer itself. That way, if the other site ever changes, this answer will still be useful.